# Dynamicaly referencing class based on a string variable

Tags: string, vba, class, variables, declaration

I'm fairly new to vba. I have a vba script that basically connects to my database using the ADODB class and returns a recordset with a bunch of information in. One column is entitled Class and it will contain the name of a Class that i'm looking to use in vb, the Class I want to use will change based on the value in the row. Is there a way I can declare and instantiate an object of this class based on the string I receive from each field under the column class. The purpose being that I need  information for each row based on the class it contains  without having to account for all possibilities.

for example

```
 Dim Class as string

 Class = Array(1, 4) ' Array(1, 4) contains Maths Class

 Dim x as Class

 Set x = New Class
```

if for example the particular Class is Math that would equate to

```
 Dim x as Math

 Set x = New Math
```

Is there a Function that could return the Class based on the string value? Thanks

Comment: Look at CallByName

Comment: Do you mean Method, or Property here?

Comment: I'm with Tim: CallByName is the way to go

Comment: @TimWilliams, apologies I was getting confused, I actually want to use a string to reference a class of a particular module , see edited above

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but a simpler approach using `Select Case` would work fine - presumably there is a finite list of class types you need to handle ?